# Help for simplification

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

The known datapoints are

$\left[ \begin{matrix}
n_x & s_x & a_x & p_x \\
n_y & s_y & a_y & p_y \\
n_z & s_z & a_z & p_z \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{matrix}\right]$

where

$$\begin{align}
n_x &=           -\sin\phi_1\sin\phi_2 + \cos\phi_1\cos\phi_2\cos\theta_1 \\
n_y &= \phantom{-}\cos\phi_1\sin\phi_2+ \sin\phi_1\cos\phi_2\cos\theta_1\\
n_z &= -\cos\phi_2\sin\theta_1 \\[6pt]
s_x &= -\sin\phi_1\cos\phi_2 - \cos\phi_1\sin\phi_2\cos\theta_1 \\
s_y &= \phantom{-}\cos\phi_1\cos\phi_2 - \sin\phi_1\sin\phi_2\cos\theta_1 \\
s_z &= \phantom{-}\sin\phi_2\sin\theta_1 \\[6pt]
a_x &= \cos\phi_1\sin\theta_1 \\
a_y &= \sin\phi_1\sin\theta_1 \\
a_z &= \cos\theta_1 \\[6pt]
p_x &= h_x + r_1\cos\phi_1\cos\theta_1 +r_2\left(- \sin\phi_1\sin\phi_2 + \cos\phi_1\cos\phi_2\cos\theta_1\right) + d_2\cos\phi_1\sin\theta_1  \\
p_y &= h_y + r_1\sin\phi_1\cos\theta_1 + r_2\left(\phantom{-}\cos\phi_1\sin\phi_2 + \cos\phi_2\sin\phi_1\cos\theta_1\right)  + d_2\sin\phi_1\sin\theta_1 \\
p_z &= h_z - r_1\sin\theta_1 - r_2\cos\phi_2\sin\theta_1 + d_2\cos\theta_1 
\end{align}$$

$px$, $py$, and $pz$ can be simplified to

$$\begin{align}
p_x &= h_x + r_1\cos\phi_1\cos\theta_1 +r_2 n_x + d_2 a_x\\
p_y &= h_y + r_1\sin\phi_1\cos\theta_1 +r_2 n_y + d_2 a_y\\
p_z &= h_z - r_1\sin\theta_1 + r_2 n_z+ d_2a_z 
\end{align}$$

I've gotten my simplification to here but I keep finding it hard to find an elegant way to remove the other sine and cosine terms so that we're able to solve the unknown $(h_x, h_y, h_z, r_1, r_2, d_2)$ relative to 6 or more datapoints matrices.

Comment: Unreadable. Please learn how to format mathematics on this website. There is a help menu.

Comment: Use \ before sine cosine phi theta ,

Comment: And _ for index numbers \theta_1 for example